# Terminal rule ID not matching valid values for ID

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I'm trying to define a rule where one element is the perfect candidate for the common terminal rule *ID*. When I launch the editor to test with sample code, the *ID* rule is not matched for the string "ABC":

```
Define : ABC : Holder_1
```

I get **"mismatched input 'ABC' expecting RULE_ID"**.

Is there something in my grammar conflicting with the ID rule to cause this error?

This is my grammar file:

```
grammar com.testco.Test with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals 
import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore
generate defwiz "http://www.testco.com/Test"

Define_Holder:
  'Definition' ':' holder_name=ID ':' holder_number=HOLDER_NUMBER (':' attribute=define_attr)? (':' pad=holder_pad)?
;

holder_pad:
  HEX
;

Type:
  TYPE_TERM ':' type_value=TYPE_VAL
;


//***************** TERMINALS *****************
terminal TYPE_TERM:
 'Type_' INT+
;  

terminal PROFILE:
  (PROFILE_ID)(PROFILE_ID)'.'(PROFILE_ID)(PROFILE_ID)
;

terminal HOLDER_NUMBER returns ecore:: EString:
  'Holder_' INT+; 

terminal HEX returns ecore:: EString :
  ('0'..'9'|'A'..'F')
;

terminal PROFILE_ID  : '^'?('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')*;


//***************** ENUMS *****************
enum define_attr:
  BINARY='Binary' |
  SCRAMBLE='Scramble' |
  FORCESIZE='ForceSize' |
  FIXEDSIZE='FixedSize'
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule PROFILE_ID shadows the ID rule for almost every case (except for the underscore).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's likely that lexer scans `ABC` as `HEX` terminal. Try to define the latter, for example, as follows:

```
terminal HEX returns ecore:: EString :
 '0x' ('0'..'9'|'A'..'F')
;
```

Comment: The language I'm trying to model doesn't recognize the _0x_ prefix, it expects the value given conforms to the type of the function it is being given to (variable have not type). It's a very funky language, for sure.